# Запятая в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая после скобок?

> Важно знать, что при снижении давления за конденсатоотводчиком (что
>   является необходимым условием его функционирования), конденсат,
>   который представлял собой жидкую среду перед ним, превращается в
>   двухфазную среду за ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужна ли здесь запятая после скобок?

НЕ НУЖНА.

Простое предложение, обособленных оборотов нет: *при снижении давления за конденсатоотводчиком конденсат [такой-то] превращается в двухфазную среду за ним.*

Answer (score 1):

Скобки не влияют на необходимость постановки запятых по другим мотивам. Здесь таких мотивов нет. Уберите заключенное в скобки - разве нужна запятая?

Хотя, оборот "при снижении давления..." несет некоторый смысл причинности, но того явно недостаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Если по тем или иным условиям, на месте "разрыва" вставной конструкцией требовались какие-нибудь знаки препинания, их следовало бы поместить после скобок.

В приведенном вами примере  перед скобками запятая не ставится, поэтому и после скобок не нужно ставить запятую.